# Suggest an HTML editor or IDE for canvas

Tags: html, ide, editor, html5-canvas

I'm in need of great text editor or IDE that has real-time or built-in preview feature for HTML5's canvas element. Preferable, the one that has feature of whenever I change the code, the preview will change too. Another question, is there browser that can do it?

For example: http://www.htmlinstant.com/

HTML Instant was great but of course I need the other features of common editors such as syntax highlighting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [**CodeMirror**](http://codemirror.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codepen.io/ is reeeeally nice

modify some code in this project and notice how it updates immediately
http://codepen.io/onedayitwillmake/pen/Evyfp

Comment: Thank you mattnull, I believe codepen is really greeeaaat but for some reason I don't want web-based. Anyway, I will use codepen for now.